# How can I change the docking of devtools in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

VS Code was docking devtools pane within the window before. Now, It opens a new window that increases back and forth. Is there any way to dock it back? I tried a few settings they did not work. Also, there is no dock icon as in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started with vscode v1.74 and is an electron bug.  See [The developer tools become a floating window](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168454).

There is a fix reported there.  **Disable** the setting

```
Windows > Experimental > Windows Control Overlay: Enabled
```

You will be prompted to restart vscode and then opening the Dev Tools will be docked as before.  Apparently, the Electron bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In the devtools panel, click the vertically-aligned three dots at the top right. That will open up a context menu. You will see a "Dock side" entry with different icons signifying option values for that setting. You probably accidentally clicked the one that makes it pop the devtools out into its own window. Select whichever option you actually want there.

There's a related bug that started in VS Code 1.74: [The developer tools become a floating window #168454](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168454) that was caused by an electron + Window Controls Overlay (a MS Windows thing) bug: [[Bug]: WCO on Windows occludes dev tools #34129](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34129), which you can work around by toggling the `window.experimental.windowControlsOverlay.enabled` setting off. If you're curious, further explanation of the bug's impact on this behaviour of VS Code can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168454#issuecomment-1697135264). As a result of that WCO issue, [a draft PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/192114/) has been written to add a `window.developerToolsLocation` setting. The workaround will apparently no longer be needed in the September 2023 release of VS Code (version 1.83 I think), courtesy of this Pull Request: [chore: bump electron@25.8.1 #193060](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/193060), which purportedly fixes this issue.